# How to Pass byte[] from Excel vba to web service

Tags: vba, excel

i want to pass byte[] from excel vba to web service.

Below is the code which will convert file to byte[].

```
Dim bytFile() As Byte
bytFile = GetFileBytes("C:\test.doc")
```

below code is used to call webservice. bytFile  is my parameter

```
Dim XMLHttp As Object: Set XMLHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
XMLHttp.Open "POST", Service + "/PassExcelData", False
XMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
XMLHttp.send "filebyte=" & bytFile
```

But i am not able to pass it to webservice. i am getting error at last line. So i just want to is it possible? If not, which way i can achieve this?

I have also tried below code

```
Function FileToStr(ByVal strFile As String) As String
 Dim hFile As Long
 hFile = FreeFile
 Open strFile For Input As #hFile
 FileToStr = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
 Close #hFile
End Function
```

and called it as:

```
XMLHttp.send "filebyte=" & FileToStr(file path).
```

but it returned the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't append a byte array with & operator. get the text of the file using
use this function

```
Function FileToStr(ByVal strFile As String) As String
     Dim hFile As Long
     hFile = FreeFile
     Open strFile For Input As #hFile
     FileToStr = Input$(LOF(hFile), hFile)
     Close #hFile
 End Function
```

and then do 
    XMLHttp.send "filebyte=" & FileToStr("Path to your file")

You can comment out the GetFileBytes line

Comment: Let me try, i will let you know the result